# jquery: onClick function for any id that's a number?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have several dynamically generated div id's, each of which will be a number, and want a click handler that will execute when a link inside any of these div id's is clicked, and assign the value of a variable to that div id, eg:

```
var someNumber

<div id=someNumber>link here</div>

$('#clicking any div id that's a number should run this').click(function() {
   someVariable = this.id
});
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="click" id=1>Div 1</div>
<div class="click" id=2>Div 2</div>
<div class="click" id=3>Div 3</div>
<div class="click" id=4>Div 4</div>

<script>
    $('.click').click(function () {
        dowork($(this));
    });


function dowork(element){
     id = $(element).attr('id')
    if(isNaN(id)){
        " is not a number";
     }else{
        " is a number"
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get parent `<div>` of clicked link. Then use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get `id` attribute value.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
  console.log(clickedDiv);
  return false; // prevent following a link
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1"><a href="/abc">Link 1</a></div>
<div id="id2"><a href="/def">Link 2</a></div>
<div id="id3"><a href="/ghi">Link 3</a></div>
```